# Websphere clusters + Struts application

Tags: java, deployment, struts-1, websphere-6.1, struts1

I have one Struts application, which is deployed on Websphere:

- Websphere Server

  - Cell

    - Cluster-1
    - Cluster-2

I have deployed same application on both clusters.

- On cluster 1, my application works fine.
- On cluster 2, my application is not working properly. On loading the application it shows below error

  > **SRVE0190E: File not found: `/<bean:message key='path' />/SomeCSS.css`**

What could be the problem ?

Comment: You cannot deploy same application twice in one Cell, so probably your second application either was not deployed or started correctly.

Comment: We have two applications which have been deployed on same cell with different clusters. and both are working fine!

Comment: The applications must have different name and different root-context.

Comment: @Gas: Yaah, for each application have different name like app & app1. but still facing issue.

Comment: If you have different `context-root` then  `/<bean:message key='path' />/SomeCSS.css`  is a absolute path not relative and is different for both apps. Remove the leading `/` from that entry to use relative path or check what is in the path key. It should be relative to the context root.